# How to resolve SSLProtocol Syntax Error

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, ssl-certificate-errors

I am trying to install an SSL Certificate.

When I restart apache I get this error:

**SSLProtocol: Illegal protocol '\xe2\x80\x93SSLv2'**

Here are my conf file directives:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName example.com
    ServerAlias *.example.com
    DocumentRoot /home/abc/public_html/
    SSLEngine on
    SSLProtocol all -SSLv2 -SSLv3
    SSLCipherSuite ALL:!ADH:!EXPORT:!SSLv2:RC4+RSA:+HIGH:+MEDIUM:+LOW
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/mycert_example_com_cert.cer
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/mycert.key
    SSLCACertificateFile /etc/ssl/mycert_example_com_interm.cer
    ErrorLog logs/sites_error_log
    CustomLog logs/sites_access_log common
</VirtualHost>
```

**Amended:**

I resolved the error using @MichaelHampton's catch on the hyphen.

Now when I restart apache the http service daemon does not start either with `apachectl restart` or `apachectl stop` and `apache start`

So I stepped through the directives, 1-by-1 commenting and uncommenting and the moment I uncomment `SSLEngine on` http does not restart.

So I wonder...this is the second  container in the conf file. The first container also has an `SSLEngine on` directive. Do I need to repeat that directive in each container?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your configuration line doesn't contain the expected hyphen (`-`). It instead contains an en dash (`–`). It looks similar, but it's a completely different character.

In fact, it appears both of them are en dashes.

This can happen if you copy and paste from a web site which has unhelpfully changed hyphens to en dashes.

To solve the problem, replace both of the en dashes with hyphens.

Comment: Excellent @MichaelHampton...I'll give that a try. Thank you for seeing that!

Comment: Well, that was not the problem. Restarting apache brought the server down again.

Comment: I never said you didn't have _other_ problems!

Comment: You are correct @MichaelHampton...you did not say that :)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure mod_ssl is being loaded. You should be able to tell from inspecting the error log (on ubuntu that would be in /var/log/apache2).

Comment: Ok, thank you @ztron. I will check in the morning. In the meantime, does mod_ssl need to be  defined within the <virtualhost> container? I ask, because this is the 2nd <virtualhost> continer in the conf file and the default ssl cert is installed and runs fine.